# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at Object.Route.setUrlParams when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I have a simple factory set up to receive a list of objects, however for some reason I keep gettin the

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>       at Object.angular.module.factory.Route.setUrlParams

On further inspection, it seems that the url in Route.prototype is undefined. I have this factory working in other places in the app, just not on this one page and only happens on refresh.

The actual code to get the list:

```
$scope.facilityList = new FacilityList.query();
```

And the FacilityList factory:

```
.factory('FacilityService', function($http, $resource, ResourceDirectoryService){
            return $resource(ResourceDirectoryService.getFacilityList(), {}, {
                'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
            });
        });
```

The resourceDirectory returns a URL predetermined in the Java backend code. Again, this has worked in other places in the app except for one page and breaks on refresh.

The following is relevant code from the app.js config:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
.when('/user/facilityList', {
      templateUrl: 'views/userFacilityList.tpl.html',
      controller: 'UserFacilityListCtrl',
      role: 'staffView'
})
```

Tried using resolve, same error, now in app.js:

```
.when('/user/facilityList', {
          templateUrl: 'views/userFacilityList.tpl.html',
          controller: 'UserFacilityListCtrl',
          role: 'staffView',
              resolve: {
                  resolvedFacilities: ['$q', 'FacilityService', function($q, FacilityService){
                      var deferred = $q.defer();
                      FacilityService.query(
                          function (resp){
                              deferred.resolve(resp);
                          });
                      return deferred.promise;
                  }]
              }
```

Comment: Could you show some router and config code?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: I am not sure that there is a link between the url refreshed and the factory. But are you sure that `ResourceDirectoryService.getFacilityList()` return something before the loading the template/controller? If not, you can use $routeProvider.route.resolve to wait for a response.

Comment: Just tried that too, same error as before just in app.js this time